# How can I extract information in the lines between two headers?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and am attempting to use this currently nonfunctioning code to extract information between two headers from a text file.

```
with open('toysystem.txt','r') as f:
  start = '<Keywords>'
  end = '</Keywords>'
  i = 0
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
   if line == start:
    keywords = lines[i+1]
 i += 1
```

For reference, the text file looks like this:

```
<Keywords>
GTO
</Keywords>
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong with the code? Or perhaps a different way to approach this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- lines read from file contains newline symbol at the end, so we probably should [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) them,
- `f` object is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), so we don't need to use `str.readlines` method here.

So we can write something like

```
with open('toysystem.txt', 'r') as f:
    start = '<Keywords>'
    end = '</Keywords>'
    keywords = []
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == start:
            break
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == end:
            break
        keywords.append(line)
```

gives us

```
>>> keywords
['GTO\n']
```

---

If you don't need newline at the end of keywords as well – strip them too:

```
with open('toysystem.txt', 'r') as f:
    start = '<Keywords>'
    end = '</Keywords>'
    keywords = []
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == start:
            break
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == end:
            break
        keywords.append(line.rstrip())
```

gives

```
>>> keywords
['GTO']
```

But in this case it will be better to create stripped lines [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) like

```
with open('toysystem.txt', 'r') as f:
    start = '<Keywords>'
    end = '</Keywords>'
    keywords = []
    stripped_lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    for line in stripped_lines:
        if line == start:
            break
    for line in stripped_lines:
        if line == end:
            break
        keywords.append(line)
```

which does the same.

---

Finally, if you need your lines in the next parts of script, we can use `str.readlines` and stripped lines generator:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    start = '<Keywords>'
    end = '</Keywords>'
    keywords = []
    lines = f.readlines()
    stripped_lines = (line.rstrip() for line in lines)
    for line in stripped_lines:
        if line.rstrip() == start:
            break
    for line in stripped_lines:
        if line.rstrip() == end:
            break
        keywords.append(line.rstrip())
```

gives us

```
>>> lines
['<Keywords>\n', 'GTO\n', '</Keywords>\n']
>>> keywords
['GTO']
```

## Further reading

- [*file objects*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects),
- [*iterators*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) (including *file iterators*),
- [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),
- [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Python re module insted and parse it using regex?!

```
import re
with open('toysystem.txt','r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    # will find all the expressions in the file and return a list of values inside the (). You can extend the expression according to your need.
    keywords = re.findall(r'\<keywords\>\s*\n*\s*(.*?)\s*\n*\s*\<\/keywords\>')
    print(keywords)
```

from your file it will print

```
['GTO']
```

for more about regular expression and python check [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm)
, [For python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)